# Catch-all URL rewrite on Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a short URL for a GAE app, so I used [UrlRewriteFilter](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/), but I can't get it set up correctly. Basically, the user is given this:

- test.com/012a-bc

and the page that they should be redirected to is

- test.com/vote.jsp?id=012a-bc

At the moment it's working with the `urlrewrite.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <from>/([0-z]+)</from>
        <to last="true">/vote.jsp?id=$1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

The problem is that all URLs now redirect to this, so for example

- test.com/thankyou.jsp?id=0123

still runs the page at vote.jsp. What should I do to get it to redirect only when the URL isn't found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following rule:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/([\w-]+)$</from>
   <to last="true">/vote.jsp?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Where `[\w-]+` is at least one any word character (letter, number, underscore) including `-` (dash character). You use `^` and `$` to anchor beginning and end of checked text.

---

[UrlRewriteFilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html) documentation says

> When executing a rule the filter will (very simplified) loop over all
>   rules and for each do something like this psuedo code:

```
Pattern.compile(<from> element); pattern.matcher(request url);
matcher.replaceAll(<to> element); 
if ( <condition> elements match && matcher.find() ) {
    handle <set> elements (if any)
    execute <run> elements (if any)
    perform <to> element (if any) 
}
```

That's why you have to use beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) string regular expression anchors