# Using UrlRewriteFilter to remove .html extension from page? – Using GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

having a bit of difficulty getting my url to write properly. I just found out about [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and it seems to be exactly what I need, since it's kind of difficult to rewrite urls using Java with GAE (it's disgustingly simple using python/go and app.yaml, but with Java it's a major pain in the ass for some reason, and I have to use Java). Here's what I have —

```
<rule>
    <from>^/test.html$</from>
    <to>/test</to>
</rule>
```

I just want people to be able to type `mysite.com/test` instead of `mysite.com/test.html`. Am I going about this the right way? When I use this code above I get a `HTTP ERROR 500` caused by `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the UrlRewriteFilter by Paul Tuckey during my research for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575807/). That didn't work well for me, for two reasons.

- I didn't like the idea of filtering all requests with the UrlRewriteFilter because all requests will have to be routed through app engine instances, and therefor cutting out the content delivery network
- I could be wrong about this but if i remember correctly, during my quick excourse into the UrlRewriteFilter i found that the filter forwards internally to the static content, which doesn't work because the appengine instance itself is not set up to serve static content - only the content delivery network does that.

What i did recently looks like this:

```
public class RewriteFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        log.info("Proxy Servlet for: " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("index.html"); OutputStream os = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()) {
            int read = is.read(buffer);
            while (read > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                read = is.read(buffer);
            }

        }

        // chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

While being really ugly, this works, even if just for the index.html page (well i could change that with filter init params and defining multiple filters).

**But why does it work where the UrlRewriteFilter doesn't?**

The answer is quite simple. This filter servlet doesn't forward internally to static content but serves the content itself. Since this filter will only become active for urls i specify by `<url-pattern>` below `<filter-mapping>` in the web.xml, i can live with the slight performance dip when serving through this filter. If anyone found a better way to do this, please leave a comment.